# OSX the login switch screen turns off the WIFI

Tags: macos, networking, login-screen

I have a program that is downloading a file, and I enter the login window while attending 
(so that I can leave and nobody can use my computer).

unfortunately, OSX automatically turns off the wifi while in the login screen,
so my download stops.

(the download does not stop if I have the ethernet cable connected).

so, how can I prevent OSX turning off the wifi while in the login window?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you don't set the option to always require a password from the screensaver and/or lock the screen when leaving?

Comment: i do that. i lock the computer (fast user switching -> login window).
and that turns off the wifi (as i said, if i use the ethernet cable instead of wifi, the download continues)

Comment: There was a thread about this over on a sibling site: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/71884/wi-fi-disconnects-when-i-lock-the-mac, though doesn't seem like there's a simple fix (or a known cause)

Comment: thanks ernie; please repeat your post as an answer so that i can mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: thanks ernie; please repeat your post as an answer so that i can mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a thread about this over on a sibling site:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/71884/wi-fi-disconnects-when-i-lock-the-mac

Doesn't seem like there's a simple fix (or a known cause)?

Comment: thanks! for me it worked by installing the "Lock Me Now" application, and choosing the option "lock" instead of "login window".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Fast User Switching does something special (or enables sleep faster than usual). Alternatively you could do the following:

- Preferences -> Security -> General (first tab): Set option to immediately require password if the screen saver kicks in
- Preferences -> Desktop/Screensaver -> Screensaver: Define an active corner to start the screen saver

Then instead of using Fast User Switching just move the mouse into the corner defined above and let the screen saver kick in.

Answer (score 0):

Find out what the network interface is for your wifi. It's "en1" for this example (the MAC addresses have been replaced with 00s):

```
ifconfig
en1: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500  
ether 00:00:00:00:00:00  
inet6 0000::000:0000:0000:0000%en1 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x5
inet 10.0.1.16 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 10.0.1.255
media: autoselect
status: active
```

Then, you need to set up the airport util for your wireless card to tell it not to shut off:

```
cd /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources
sudo ./airport en1 prefs DisconnectOnLogout=NO
```

This answer is from https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/71884/wi-fi-disconnects-when-i-lock-the-mac.

Answer (score -1):

So you log out? That stops the download. Don't logout! I don't think the wifi turns off when you logout. The download program simply stops working. Logging out stops all apps that are running under your account. You may have a cron script running, that will keep working.

Turn on the screensaver with password protection if you want to prevent others to access your computer.

Comment: no, i don't logout. i lock the computer (fast user switching -> login window).

Comment: (as i said, if i use the ethernet cable instead of wifi, the download continues)